# Excel Cell Validation

Tags: excel

I have a cell in excel with a default drop-down entry as "No". If people are to save it, I want excel to throw an error and not allow them to save it. The cell entry needs to be changed manually to the other entry, which is "Yes", before saving. Could some one help me with a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a code for me site, but take a look at the following and post back if you come unstuck at anypoint, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057.aspx

Comment: What have you tried? Check out the [BeforeSave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057.aspx) event

Comment: yes. I tried it. But is it possible to make it run automatically, that is when the user tries to save the excel or close the excel.

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Sheets("Springer - Project Planner").Range("C45").Value = "No" Then
    Cancel = True
    Response = MsgBox("Are Special Instructions, Art/CE & Production-LaTeX intake queries updated in Spike?", vbCritical, "Spike Update Error!")
End If
End Sub